# Update item ID when deleting

Tags: android, mysql

I have 5 empty TextViews where I add the names. After adding a name, it is stored in a database. The database consist on 2 columns, the item ID and the item NAME. This is an example of what I'm doing:

```
- Mark1    //ID=1, NAME= Mark1
- Mark2    //ID=2, NAME= Mark2
- Mark3    //ID=3, NAME= Mark3
- Empty
- Empty
```

I add and edit perfectly the textViews, but I'm facing a problem when deleting. This has something to do with the way I'm getting the values from the database, I'll explain:

Every time the app starts, or I edit, add or delete one element, what I do is get the items from the database, get them into a Map, and copy them into the textviews (whose at a first time are invisible) making visible just the ones that have a name setted.

This is the code I use to do that:

```
public void getTravelers() {
    /*Create map where store items*/
    Map<Integer, String> nameList = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    /*Lon in providers query() method to get database's items and save them into the map*/
    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(TravelersProvider.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, null, null, null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            nameList.put(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Travelers._ID))), c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Travelers.NAME)));
        }while(c.moveToNext());
    }
    if (c != null && !c.isClosed()) {
        c.close();
    }
    /*Check size*/
    int size = nameList.size();
    if (size >= 1) {
        /*Save items in TextViews*/
        //TODO: This is the code I should fix
        for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
            if (i==1) {
                traveler1.setText(nameList.get(i).toString());
                traveler1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            if (i==2) {
                traveler2.setText(nameList.get(i).toString());
                traveler2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            if (i==3) {
                traveler3.setText(nameList.get(i).toString());
                traveler3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            if (i==4) {
                traveler4.setText(nameList.get(i).toString());
                traveler4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            if (i==5) {
                traveler5.setText(nameList.get(i).toString());
                traveler5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem comes in the for loop. Let's supposse that from the items named above, I want to delete `Mark2` with ID=2, so then the size of the new Map would be 2, and it would enter to `(i == 1)` and `(i == 2)`. But when entering to this last one, it would do *traveler2.setText(nameList.get(**2**).toString());* and as seen, there is no element existing with the ID=2 because that is the one that I've deleted and it throws a NPE.

So my question is, what would be the right way to do this without facing this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I get what I need just changing the Key value of the Map that was the same as the ID of the database:

```
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    int key = 0;
    do {
        key++;
        nameList.put(key, c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Travelers.NAME)));
    }while(c.moveToNext());
}
if (c != null && !c.isClosed()) {
     c.close();
}
```

Basically this way I don't need to change nothing more as now the key value of the Map will match with the Textview position

Answer (score 0):

You should go for switch case other than for loop. Than code will not be in loop.

Comment: I didn't thoght about it but seems a better aproach that mine's... How would you manage the Textviews and the item's IDs? Maybe should I edit the ID of an item f.e. if i delete item with ID=2 and I have another item with ID=3, edit this last one to have ID=2? or this would be a bit messy and there is another solution?